# tflite defendance is not working with flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, flutter-dependencies, tensorflow-lite, flutter-test

I am new to flutter.  I am making an action recognize mobile app.  But tflite defense doesn't work with flutter.  Does anyone know a solution?

The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.

this is the error. anyone can help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

change the `compile to api` you will find a file in this location in windows

[screenshot shows changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvI3O.png)

```
C:\Usersyour_username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-
1.1.2\android\build.gradle
```

or you can use the relative path

```
%AppData%\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google ml kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit) for recognize things.

for example for object detection you can use [google_mlkit_object_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_object_detection)
and this base on **tflite**

this is sample code to Create an instance of tflite_model

```
final modelPath = await _getModel('assets/ml/object_labeler.tflite');
 final options = LocalObjectDetectorOptions(
  modelPath: modelPath,
  classifyObjects: true,
  multipleObjects: true,
 );
final objectDetector = ObjectDetector(options: options);
```

Comment: can I make a real-time dynamic sign language flutter application using this?

Comment: I did not understand your question, please explain

Comment: I am going to create a mobile application, Dynamic sign language recognition, and convert it into text. I already trained the TensorFlow model for this, using video frames. I convert it into tflite model to use for mobile applications. but I tried to add this tflite model file to the flutter application it show the above error. what can I do? I am a beginner at flutter.

Comment: Ok, what package are you using and what error is it giving?

Comment: i am using tflite 1.1.2  this dependance for flutter v 3.3.4 . it show "The plugin tflite uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs." this error. is there any way to create action recognition mobile application?

Comment: [tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite) doesn't work at all anymore. I wanted to use it a few months ago. It was not used. I took a [fork](https://github.com/NavidHosseini/tflite) of it and was able to run it, but in the end it didn't work as I expected, so I switched to the [google_mlkit_object_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_object_detection) package.
In my opinion, build your model with the [teachablemachine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) website and try it with my [fork](https://github.com/NavidHosseini/tflite) package and see if you get an answer or not.

Comment: https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/issues/225#issuecomment-1170954240